# CreateIntermediateDirectories->False gives error, why?

Tags: export, storage

I am on windows 7, using 11.2

Created new folder, and new notebook in it, saved it, and then typed

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
CreateArchive[NotebookDirectory[],CreateIntermediateDirectories->False]
```

It gives an error that the directory I am in do not exist. Screen shot

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Changing `False` to `True` it works.

Why using the option `False` gives an error? How to find what is causing this error?

Comment: have you tried to create at least one file in that directory to archive?

Comment: @AlbertRetey yes. I created 2 txt files in the directory. The directory also includes the notebook itself !  so it is not empty.

Comment: just played with it and the behavior looks like a bug to me (I am also on Windows, Mma 11.2), that option seems to not make much sense in the first place. Interestingly the only example is the failing case, so maybe it is failing always by design :-). Probably the behavior is more useful on other platforms...